# C# Having trouble with TryParse

Tags: c#, tryparse

How would I add `TryParse` to this code, so if user enters a letter, it would tell him, "Not valid, please enter numbers only". I have tried a couple of ways, but it breaks my code. I have tried it with `for` and `while` loops. But, when I did get it to work, it only took 1 number, and then assigned that number to all my arrays.

```
{
    const int SIZE = 2;

    double[] array = new double[SIZE];
    Console.WriteLine("Please Sir Enter 2 numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
         array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
    Console.WriteLine("The Values you've entered are");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,8}", "index", "value");
    for (int counter = 0; counter< SIZE; counter++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("===============================================");            
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you show one of the ways you tried that didn’t work?

Comment: while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numbers))
                        {array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                        }

Comment: @Doogie please edit the question to show what you've tried so the code is properly formatted and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the while loop inside of the for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   double num = 0;
   while(!Double.TryParse(input, out num))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Not valid, please enter numbers only");
       input = Console.ReadLine();
   }
    array[i] = num;
}
```

Comment: I get error with this line, array[i] = Double.Parse(val); CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string', Plus we have not gone over var we have to use int, double, decimal and string for now. I tried using number for all var but did not work.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `array[i] = val;` after the while? `TryParse` did the parse and the value is in `val`, no need to Parse again.

Comment: There is no variable `num`. How could that possibly work for you?

Comment: `{
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                double num = 0;
                while (!Double.TryParse(input, out num))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input try again.");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                array[i] = (num);
            }`

Comment: how do you add code to comment so it looks right? I search and it said add backtick before and after code.

Answer (score 1):

For getting validated input from the user (especially when the type is expected to be something other than a string), I find it really useful to use a helper method.

The method below takes in a string that is displayed to the user (the prompt for input), and then continues to ask the user for input until they enter a valid number (`TryParse` is part of the `while` condition).

It also takes in an optional function parameter that can be used to validate the input, in case you want to place additional restrictions on it. The function is defined to take in a `double` (the user input) and return a `bool` (`true` if the input is valid):

```
private static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt, Func<double, bool> validator = null)
{
    double result;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             (validator != null && !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}
```

To use this in your code, you would just do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Please sir, enter {SIZE} numbers");
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    array[i] = GetDoubleFromUser($" Enter number #{i + 1}: ");
}
```

**Output**

[image: Image of console output of code sample above]

---

But other times you may want to restrict the number even further, in which case you can pass a validation method to the function. One simple way to do this is to pass the function as a lambda expression. For example this expression: `i => i > 10` means "return the result of the comparison if `i` is greater than `10`", or in other words, "return `true` if `i > 10`, otherwise return `false`".

You could pass this to our `GetDoubleFromUser` method like this:

```
double greaterThan10 = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter a number greater than 10: ", i => i > 10);
```

and now the method will keep looping while the input is not a number or the input is not greater than 10!

**Output**

[image: Image of console output of code sample above]

Comment: I'm not answering a homework question, just showing one way to think about the problem. I think it's good to give an answer that cannot just be copy-pasted and turned in as homework.  

Comment: I don't see which part of those threads applies to this answer... can you tell me?

Comment: @Strom  I believe the guideline for images containing text applies to text that people would copy and paste, like code samples and exception messages. I'm curious why you want formatted text for these output results? What benefit does that provide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189235/discussion-between-strom-and-rufus-l).